# I have issues with stdclass [brackets] and I cant tell why

Tags: php, stdclass

I built a website on my computer, using XAMPP with the most recent php version and everything looks fine so far. Now, I just bought a DNS, web host, etc, the only problem I always get in every page is exactly this :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/cbifina1/public_html/classes/Credit.php on line 61

And this is what you found on that line :

```
$this->_db->results()[$x]->form_id
```

in another page, I had the same problem and I fixed

```
$this->_db->results()[0]->id
```

with

```
$this->_db->first()->id
```

but with that variable used in a loop, I am stuck here.

So why is my brackets unreadable? My php server are at php version 5.3.28..I don't think this can be the problem..

Any suggestions? :/

EDITED BELOW 5/22/14 -------------------------------------------

So let's say I have these 2 functions here

```
public function results() {
    return $this->_results;
}

public function first() {
    return $this->results()[0];
}
```

How can I get rid of [0] if I am using php below 5.4?

Comment: This usage ( _db->results()[$x]) is a feature of php 5.4 so it is a version issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you need 5.4 to use that construct. [The docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-101) say;

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

EDIT: Your followup regarding how to change the code for 5.3 requires using a temporary variable and index on that instead. That means translating;

```
public function first() {
    return $this->results()[0];
}
```

...to...

```
public function first() {
    $tmp = $this->results();
    return $tmp[0];
}
```

Comment: @matt_bois Updated to answer your followup question.